# fixed header div with scrollable div below

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place two divs one above the other. The top one has a fixed size. The bottom one needs to fill the rest of the page height, without making the page higher if it's content is too big.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="top-padding"></div>
    <div id="stuff">
        some content
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        End of content.
    </div>
</div><!-- content -->
```

My attempt so far is: http://jsfiddle.net/b4fEE/

The problem I have is that the green div is too big. I need as way to specify it's height as

```
100% - 30px
```

I'd prefer to do this in pure css, but I will resort to javascript/jquery if necessary.

Comment: @SteveP : #stuff {
    overflow-x:auto;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

Comment: try `height:calc(100%-30px);` with vendor prefixes

Comment: @SteveP : try my solution in your fiddle it self. It works. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
#stuff {
   overflow-x:auto;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   top:30px;  /* as the height of the other div is 30px */
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   position:absolute;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4fEE/12/)**

Comment: The <br> tags where simply a way to make the content bigger than the available space to force a scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Thanks for your css suggestion. It works perfectly for me, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In case if anyone wants to solve this keeping things in normal flow, nowadays this can be done using the [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) layout model as shown below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #C9E6FF;
}
#top-padding {
  height: 30px;
  flex: none;
  background: blue;
}
#stuff {
  flex: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
/*for demo purpose */

#stuff p {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="top-padding"></div>
  <div id="stuff">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

And in case if anyone wants to solve this keeping things in normal flow and without using flex, then solution is as follows:

```css
html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #content {
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #C9E6FF;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 300px;
    }

    #top-padding {
        background: blue;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #stuff {
        overflow-x:auto;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        height: calc(100vh - 30px);
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="top-padding"></div>
        <div id="stuff">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
       </div>
   </div>
```