# Scrollable div below non-fixed height div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place two divs one above the other. The top div should stay always visible (not scrolling). The div below contains a list, and if the list is too long, and overflows the window/containing div, the div should be scrollable. When defining the height of the top div, it's good, but the content of the top div may change, so the height should not be fixed [(like in this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293941/fixed-header-div-with-scrollable-div-below).

[My attempt on Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/8YKj9f7A1HqZF65HxB3v?p=preview)

Is it possible with pure CSS, without JavaScript calculation?

#### Edit:

The list should strech to the bottom of the screen/container div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some not too obvious CSS trickery to get the behaviour you're after, importantly any scrollable content needs to be within a separate container in a CSS table's cell, with `overflow-y` set, and a height of 100%. The top cell then needs a height of 1% to auto expand as appropriate.

Then all you need to do is set the tables `height` and `max-height` as appropriate.

By using CSS tables, you get a lot more flexibility when it comes to layout calculation/manipulation in terms of *relating* the sizes of elements

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/MvTB6/1/)

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.row:first-of-type >.cell {
    background:lightgreen;
    height:1%;
}
.row:last-of-type >.cell {
    background:pink;
}
#list {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>This is text in the <strong>list-head</strong>, it's content may change, so the height of the div shouldn't be fixed, but should stay always visible (not scrolling).</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div id="list">
                <div class="list-element">These are list elements.</div>
                <div class="list-element">If the list is too long</div>
                <div class="list-element">and reaches the bottom</div>
                <div class="list-element">the list should be scrollable.</div>
                <div class="list-element">(And only the list</div>
                <div class="list-element">not together with the <strong>list-head</strong>.)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think, I wasn't clear enough in the question: the list should stretch to the bottom of the screen/container div, but the height of your table is fixed. (Solution with table is okay.) I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Csati - as noted above, simply change the height of the table, the height given above is an example only

Answer (score -1):

Will this work for you ?

```
<div id="top" >

</div>
<div id="bottom">

</div>

<style>
#top{
display:block;
width:100%;
}
#bottom{
overflow:scroll;
display:block;
height:500px;
width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this structure

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="header">

   </div>

   <div class="content">

   </div>
</div>


.main{
    height:100%;
}

.header{
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background:#454546;
    width:100%;
}

.content{
    margin-top:53px;
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nXc6Y/)